# Custom SliceLayout {Triangle}

Tags: android, android-imageview

**What** about the following layout ?

[image]

**1st** Attempt was to create custom `RelativeLayout` with `OnDraw` overriding as follows

**SliceLayout** Class :

```
public class SliceLayout extends LinearLayout {

    public SliceLayout(Context Context, Slice Slice) {
        super(Context);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPath = Draw(Slice.A, Slice.B, Slice.C);

    }

    final static String TAG = "Slice";
    Paint mPaint;
    Path mPath;



    private Path Draw(Point A, Point B, Point C) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Draw");
        Path Pencil = new Path();
        Pencil.moveTo(A.x, A.y);
        Pencil.lineTo(B.x, B.y);
        Pencil.lineTo(C.x, C.y);
        return Pencil;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Drawing");
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }
}
```

**Slice** Class :

```
public class Slice {
    public enum Location {
        N, S, W, NE, NW, SE, SW, EN, ES
    }

    public Point A;
    public Point B;
    public Point C;

    private void Define(Point A, Point B, Point C) {
        this.A = A;
        this.B = B;
        this.C = C;
    }

    public Slice(Point Display, Location Location) {  //Display = Size of display
        switch (Location) {
        case N:
            Define(new Point(0, 0), new Point(Display.x, 0), new Point(0,
                    Display.y));
        case S:
            Define(new Point(Display.x, 0), new Point(Display.x, Display.y),
                    new Point(0, Display.y));

        default:
            Define(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

It's working but I don't need to go the heavy code low performance way also I failed to initialize components because of inheritance in XML !

**2nd** Attempt was to try creating same layout but `XML` version

I've [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228013/skewed-corner-of-imageview-drawable), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231683/how-to-create-custom-spinner-like-border-around-the-spinner-with-down-triangle-o) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517589/making-a-triangle-shape-using-xml-definitions)

---

**Question :**

I feel loose, Can you **Help** me choose the right way or **Suggest** another `proven` way !