# Spinner - how to set border around drop down list?

Tags: android, spinner

I have this spinner and want to know how I can put border around this

```
    Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerUpdateContactMethod);
    String[] items = new String[]{"1", "2", "three"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
    dropdown.setPrompt("Please select ");
    dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the prompt doesn't actually come up on the screen. Please could someone help me with this.

Comment: You'll have to create validations for it on your `onClickListener` of your submit button to open dialog.

Comment: Sorry I do't get what you meant, all i want is a border around the spinner and also a prompt to display

Comment: I also said same thing to open a dialog or prompt. For border you'll have to create an image.

Comment: Maybe this can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231683/how-to-create-custom-spinner-like-border-around-the-spinner-with-down-triangle-o

Answer (score 23, accepted):

for custom border you can create an xml file inside drawable folder

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/white_overlay_8x" />
    <corners android:radius="6dip" />
    <stroke
        android:color="@color/white"
        android:width="@dimen/dot" />

</shape>
```

and set

```
android:background=@drawable/file;
```

in your spinner(xml file of activity)

Comment: Error:(3, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'color' with value '@color/white_overlay_8x').

Comment: @jomin_george94 please replace @color/white_overlay_8x' with some color available in your color.xml or atleast replace it with a color code like "#000000" .

Comment: I am sorry but now i get this error ; Error:(106, 41) String types not allowed (at 'background' with value 'R.drawable.file.xml').

Comment: It's fine I replaced it with this : android:background="@drawable/file"

Comment: I have done what you told me to do but no difference

Comment: the link I have added is a screenshot of what I see after following your suggestion

Comment: @jomin_george94 please tell me really what do you expect ? the above code can be customized with different colors and size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74252/discussion-between-jomin-george94-and-karthika-pb).

Comment: do you know how to add borders to popup window menu? https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeZMr.png also question here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259770/toolbars-popup-menu-custom-background-color-and-borders

Answer (score 0):

this will make quite a amount of space but not a border

```
dropdown.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

you can add this to your `Spinner` instance

Best thing would be customization in which you can do a lot more than just a border