# Change spinner style in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I want to change the spinner style such that it shows a border around it. For example it needs to look like this,

[image: spinner image]

Basically same as the default style as a spinner, just with a border around it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231683/how-to-create-custom-spinner-like-border-around-the-spinner-with-down-triangle-o can give you a clue to customize and get what you want

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: Thank you  @Raghunandan it worked

Answer (score 1):

Create a new xml file like this in drawable folder and customize it like you want

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="2dp" />
<solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
<stroke
  android:width="3dp"
  android:color="@android:color/black" />
</shape>
```

Then set this shape drawable as spinner background